# Asynchronous calls order issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, asynchronous

Hi Kindly help to solve the following issue. I need to get the last id of a table through an api. So I used following code, inside my main method.So my main method is a async method.

```
var runNumber2 = await this.triggerAPI_MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2();
```

Following is the triggerAPI_MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2 method.

```
/**
        * Trigger API - MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2
        */
        public triggerAPI_MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2() {

            let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                let outputFields: string[] = [];
                let index = 0;
                let record: M3.MIRecord = new M3.MIRecord();
                record.setString("DIVI", "600");
                record.setString("INTN", "AUTO-MATCH");

                this.setActive();
                this.getData(10000, outputFields, "MDBREADMI", "GetFGLINHU2", record).then(result => {
                    if (result != null || result.length > 0) {

                        console.log('runnnnn : ' + Number((result[0].KEY1)));
                        resolve(Number(result[0].KEY1));
                    } else {
                        resolve(null);
                        this.rootScope.showError("Get Run number data retrieve fail!");
                    }
                });
            });
            return promise;
        }
```

Then based on this value, For an example say the last row key is 650, I need to add  other columns for the table (for an example,with key 651,652....). Each row contains child rows as well. The number of child rows for each parent row vary. Hence, I created a for loop inside the main for loop. prepareGLS840Api_AddBatchHead method generates the parent row, and  prepareGLS840Api_AddBatchLine method generates the child rows for each parent. both these methods, main function was done using Promise.resolve.

following is the why how I called the two methods in my main function. It iterates based on the number of rows need to be printed.

```
else {

                                    console.log('group number : ' + obj.Grouping);
                                    obj.VARIANCE = tot;

                                    this.prepareGLS840Api_AddBatchHead(obj, obj.Grouping, runNumber2);


                                    console.log('runNumber2 : ' + runNumber2);

                                    let line1 = 0;
                                    for (let j of grpd[key]) {
                                        line1 += 1;
                                        this.prepareGLS840Api_AddBatchLine(j, obj.Grouping, line1, runNumber2);
                                    }

                                    this.prepareGLS840MIApi_UpdBatch();
                                    b = b + 1;
                                    POJsonArray.push(obj);

                                    runNumber2 = Number(runNumber2) + 1;
```

Following is part of the method which prints the parent row.

```
public async prepareGLS840Api_AddBatchHead(obj, grouping, runNumber2) {

    let Company = 788;
    let Division = 600;

    console.log('Im in prepareGLS840Api_AddBatchHead');

    //RequestSearchController.runNumber = await this.triggerAPI_MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2(grouping);
    //console.log('runNumber :' + RequestSearchController.runNumber);
    var value;
    Promise.resolve(await this.triggerAPI_MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2()).then(res => {
        //if (a === 1) {
        RequestSearchController.runNumber = runNumber2+1;
        //}
```

Following this the part of a  method which creates the children rows

```
public async prepareGLS840Api_AddBatchLine(obj, grouping, line, runNumber2) {

    let Company = 788;
    let Division = 600;

    console.log('Im in prepareGLS840Api_AddBatchLine');

    var ID;
    if (obj.Grouping != null) {
        ID = 'GL';
    } else {
        ID = 'l1';
    }

    var date = new Date();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var dateD = date.getDate();
    var monthM;
    var dateDD;

    if (month < 10) {
        monthM = '0' + month;
    } else {
        monthM = month;
    }

    if (dateD < 10) {
        dateDD = '0' + dateD;
    } else {
        dateDD = dateD;
    }

    var today = date.getFullYear() + '' + monthM + '' + dateDD;

    //RequestSearchController.runNumber = await this.triggerAPI_MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2(grouping);
    //console.log('runNumber :' + RequestSearchController.runNumber);

    Promise.resolve(await this.triggerAPI_MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2()).then(res => {
        RequestSearchController.runNumber = runNumber2;
```

My main issue is, runNumber2 picks the last value of the row. but when iterates it over the for loop, I'm getting the error 'Key value 651 does not exist'
.  This error message changes time to time. I meant 'Key value XXX does not exist'.

I think the loop is not  running as I need. Is it because of these asynchronous calls. How can I fix this. Kindly help.

Comment: `Promise.resolve(await this.triggerAPI_MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2())` huh? - you havne't shown the `triggerAPI_MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2` function, so it's probably written wrong

Comment: Please kindly see my updated question. triggerAPI_MDBREADMI_GetFGLINHU2 was added